# How can I count the number of times a Link-URL contains certain text correctly in Google Data Studio?

Tags: looker-studio

i want to show in Google Data Studio (GTS) how many People clicked on links that starts with a certain URL (https://career5.successfactors.eu/)

I connected GA4 to GTS.
I then created a new field named "ClicksonApplynowButtonSAPSF" with the formula:

`IF(STARTS_WITH(Link URL, "https://career5.successfactors.eu/"),"Yes","No")`

I then get a table with

| ClicksonApplynowButtonSAPSF | Unique Users |
| --- | --- |
| No | 5000 |
| Yes | 200 |

Next I want to show "200" as figure, use it in tables and so on.

So I created a field nameed "CountSAPSF" with the formula:

`COUNT(CASE WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(ClicksonApplynowButtonSAPSF, "Yes") THEN 1 ELSE 0 END )`

I would expect the field CountSAPSF to say "200", but it doesnt.
It shows a wrong number.

What do I do wrong?

I tried everything I can think of